# How can I close carousel modal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning modal carousel  to create a image slideshow when the user click on a image thumbnail but I don't know how to create a close button to close the modal after the slideshow has been started.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="vnModal">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="thanhhoa" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#thanhhoa" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#thanhhoa" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#thanhhoa" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- The slideshow -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="http://go-ixe.com/img/thanhhoa/thanhhoa1.jpg" class="img-responsive image2" alt="ThanhHoa1" class="img-rounded">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://go-ixe.com/img/thanhhoa/thanhhoa2.jpg" class="img-responsive image2" alt="ThanhHoa2" class="img-rounded">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="http://go-ixe.com/img/thanhhoa/thanhhoa3.jpg" class="img-responsive image2" alt="ThanhHoa3" class="img-rounded">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#thanhhoa" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#thanhhoa" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>  
 </div>
```